# twilio: need to initiate a transcription of recorded calls after the call has ended

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have a small python program using the API that dials my voicemail, records the call, and transcribes the results.

The program checks at set intervals, e.g., 1 hour, 3 hours, etc., and all checks are recorded by twilio.

I know that a recording less than 25 seconds was the result of not having any new voicemail messages, and so I do not want to transcribe a recording unless it is longer than 25 seconds. (This will lower cost: checking 8 times without transcribing everything would have a minimum cost of $0.14/day if there are no new message. If I have to transcribe everything, that rises to a minimum of $0.54/day.

I do not see a method to initiate a transcription for a recording after the call has ended. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio presently does not offer the ability to transcribe audio after the call has ended.  Have you considered using the TwiML [`<Pause>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) tag to wait 25 seconds before starting your transcription recording?  If the call disconnects before 25 seconds, the Record tag will not executed and no transcription will be made.

Example:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <Response>
    <Play digits="wwwwww#ww1234wwww4321#wwwwww2"></Play>
    <Pause length="25"/>
    <Record transcribe="true" />
</Response>`

If this does not work, you can consider using Twilio's recording with another transcription API provider.